# css: element at fixed position and still be in the flow?

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, fixed

I have some buttons in a div which has overflow:auto, means, the div is scrollable, and has fixed height.  I want the buttons on the top to be at fixed position, means they will always be visible even when the div is scrolled.
I've tried some tests, setting fixed position to the buttons make them overlap and I don't want that, I want them in the flow of the document.  I can do `position:fixed` to the buttons and put some spacing between the other elements in the same div, but that will not work if the window itself is scrolled, the buttons will become out of place.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfBn5/)

Comment: Try adding the given style to the first div.  {code} <div style="position:relative;margin-top:30px">text</div> {code}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='txt-div' style='margin-top:30px;'>text</div>
```

while you scroll it will eventualy overlap,try playing around with the button div,adding a white background so you dont see the overlap

heres the full code:

```
<div style='height:100px; overflow:auto;'>
<div id='button-div' style='position:fixed;background-color:#ffffff;'>
<button>can I be at fixed position, and still not overlap?</button>
</div>
<div id='txt-div' style='margin-top:30px;'>2323</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>2323</div>
</div>
```